# Pandas resample numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

So I have a dataframe of the form: index is a date and then I have a column that consists of np.arrays with a shape of 180x360. What I want to do is calculate the weekly mean of the data set. Example of the dataframe:

```
vika                                                            geop        
1990-01-01 06:00:00  [[50995.954225, 50995.954225, 50995.954225, 50...  
1990-01-02 06:00:00  [[51083.0576138, 51083.0576138, 51083.0576138,...  
1990-01-03 06:00:00  [[51045.6321168, 51045.6321168, 51045.6321168,...  
1990-01-04 06:00:00  [[50499.8436192, 50499.8436192, 50499.8436192,...  
1990-01-05 06:00:00  [[49823.5114237, 49823.5114237, 49823.5114237,...  
1990-01-06 06:00:00  [[50050.5148846, 50050.5148846, 50050.5148846,...  
1990-01-07 06:00:00  [[50954.5188533, 50954.5188533, 50954.5188533,...  
1990-01-08 06:00:00  [[50995.954225, 50995.954225, 50995.954225, 50...  
1990-01-09 06:00:00  [[50628.1596088, 50628.1596088, 50628.1596088,...
```

What I've tried so far is the simple

```
df = df.resample('W-MON')
```

But I get this error:

> pandas.core.groupby.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I've tried to change the datatype of the column to list, but it still does not work. Any idea of how to do it with resample, or any other method?

Comment: Storing numpy arrays inside a DataFrame is not a good idea usually. You'll be quite limited in what you can do (as you're finding out). Your data is probably well suited for an `xarray.Dataset` which builds on top of numpy and pandas: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/data-structures.html, [resample](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Panel` to represent 3d data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.date_range("2012/01/01", "2012/02/01")   
p = pd.Panel(np.random.rand(len(index), 3, 4), items=index)
p.resample("W-MON")
```